# programmatic method to get a list of "published" images in wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm playing with wagtail and considering using it for a site.
In the process I'm looking into serving the site through a combination of django-storages and wagtail-bakery.

At the moment I'm trying to get the images served and want to obtain a list of wagtail images that are considered "published".

I looked at the properties of the `Image` model, but I don't see anything that sticks out as a way to define if the Image is published or not.

Is there a way to determine if an Image is published or not, or get a list of Images belonging to publshed pages?

```
>>> from wagtail.images.models import Image
>>> 
>>> img = Image.objects.all()[0]
>>> for i in sorted(dir(img)):
...     print(i)
... 
DoesNotExist
Meta
MultipleObjectsReturned
__class__
__delattr__
__dict__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__getstate__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__le__
__lt__
__module__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__setstate__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
__weakref__
_check_column_name_clashes
_check_constraints
_check_field_name_clashes
_check_fields
_check_id_field
_check_index_together
_check_indexes
_check_local_fields
_check_long_column_names
_check_m2m_through_same_relationship
_check_managers
_check_model
_check_model_name_db_lookup_clashes
_check_ordering
_check_property_name_related_field_accessor_clashes
_check_search_fields
_check_single_primary_key
_check_swappable
_check_unique_together
_do_insert
_do_update
_get_FIELD_display
_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD
_get_next_or_previous_in_order
_get_pk_val
_get_unique_checks
_has_field
_meta
_perform_date_checks
_perform_unique_checks
_save_parents
_save_table
_set_file_hash
_set_pk_val
_state
admin_form_fields
check
clean
clean_fields
collection
collection_id
created_at
date_error_message
default_alt_text
delete
file
file_hash
file_size
filename
focal_point_height
focal_point_width
focal_point_x
focal_point_y
from_db
full_clean
get_autocomplete_search_fields
get_deferred_fields
get_file_hash
get_file_size
get_filterable_search_fields
get_focal_point
get_indexed_instance
get_indexed_objects
get_next_by_created_at
get_previous_by_created_at
get_rect
get_rendition
get_rendition_model
get_search_fields
get_searchable_search_fields
get_suggested_focal_point
get_upload_to
get_usage
get_willow_image
has_focal_point
height
id
indexed_get_content_type
indexed_get_parent
indexed_get_toplevel_content_type
is_editable_by_user
is_landscape
is_portrait
is_stored_locally
objects
open_file
pk
prepare_database_save
refresh_from_db
renditions
save
save_base
search_fields
serializable_value
set_focal_point
tagged_items
tags
title
unique_error_message
uploaded_by_user
uploaded_by_user_id
usage_url
validate_unique
width
```

Comment: Doesn't wagtail-bakery handle this for you? I used it once and in my experience wagtail-bakery just includes the used image renditions. Nothing more.

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm *trying* to do a non-standard deploy using aws lambda/efs.  In this odd usecase wagtail-bakery fails to obtain media because it expects a file system object and not a django-storages s3 path.  I'm trying to do this to work around this issue, and don't want to make public all images that are _not_ published.

Comment: There is an open issue for that. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-bakery/issues/41

Comment: You might want to try and mount your file service as local drive, and switch to the default Django storage backend.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'm trying EFS, so I may be able to use default storage... I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'published' attribute because `Image` instances are not part of a workflow. Draft, publish, and un-publish are terms that belong to a `Page`.

`Image` does have a `get_usage` method.

`get_usage` lives in `wagtail.images.models.AbstractImage.get_usage` and calls `wagtail.admin.models.get_object_usage`. This doc string reads:

> "Returns a queryset of pages that link to a particular object"

Unfortunately, this will only give you images that are referenced via a database relation. It will NOT give you images used in streamfields (json). This also doesn't say much about the workflow state the related `Page` is in.

You might want to have a look at https://github.com/cfpb/wagtail-inventory